# Path to folder from localhost

Tags: php, path, localhost

In my project, I am using EasyPHP and the directory I wanted to access is 
`-> www/myP/profile_icon`:

I am trying to access profile_icon folder by using the code:

```
   $dir = "myP/profile_icon";
   $handle = opendir($dir."/");
```

However, I am getting a warning:

> Warning: opendir(myP/profile_icon/,myP/profile_icon/): The system
>   cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\myP\functions.php

Comment: try: $dir = '/www/myP/profile_icon/';

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the full path to the file:

```
$dir = "C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-12.1/www/myP/profile_icon";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
$base_dir  = 'C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\myP';
$icon_dir  = '\profile_icon';
$handle = opendir($base_dir.$icon_dir.'\');
```

As you're using PHP on Windows machine you mustn't pay attention to the use of the slashes. Linux let's us only use forward-slash `/`, however on Windows, both forward-slash `/` and back-slash `\` are used as path separator character.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in

> C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\myP\functions.php

```
$dir = __DIR__. "/profile_icon";
$handle = opendir($dir."/");
```

This keeps working and does not rely on any system specific folders. It just relies on the internal project structure.

Note that this requires PHP 5.3. For lower versions, use

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__). "/profile_icon";
```

Comment: Thanku All of You For The Answer. My problem solved jst by $dir = profile_icon .