# Echo image with php

Tags: php

I am trying to do something really simple with php but I can not find where I have the mistake! So, I want to echo an image like this (part of the code):

```
    $file_path[0] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/image_archive/".$last_file[0];
    echo $file_path[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<img src=\".$file_path[0].\" alt=\"error\">";
```

I must have some kind of error when I echo the img tag but I can not find it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <div class="content">
   <h1> Map</h1>
  <?php

  include '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/web_application_functions/last_file.php'; 
  $last_file = last_file(); 

 $file_path[0] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/image_archive/".$last_file[0];
echo $file_path[0];
echo "<br>";
echo '<img src="' . $file_path[0] . '" alt="error">';
?>
<!-- end .content --></div>
```

Comment: Did you check the resulting HTML that was sent to the browser?

Comment: I get the broken image symbol.. Not even the alt..

Comment: @ Pranav Kapoor: yes. Its an array. When I echo it, I get the corresponding path.

Comment: You should not echo the full path on the system, but the path relative to the document root of your web server, in your case - htdocs

Comment: @popnoodles: Sorry but I don't get your point.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that the above is outputting, this should make it clearer to everyone

Comment: I just posted the HTML. Not much of it.

Comment: you haven't posted the HTML you've posted the code that makes it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a path either relative to the server root, or the current file.

```
echo "<img src='/php_test/image_archive/" . $last_file[0] . "' alt='error'>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<img src=\".$file_path[0].\" alt=\"error\">";
```

is wrong

```
echo "<img src=\"".$file_path[0]."\" alt=\"error\">";
```

is what you think you're doing

It's useful to use single quotes so you don't make this mistake

```
echo '<img src="' . $file_path[0] . '" alt="error">';
```

Secondly

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/image_archive/` looks like a path not a directory

Perhaps you mean

```
$file_path[0] = "/php_test/image_archive/".$last_file[0];
```

or

```
$file_path[0] = "image_archive/".$last_file[0];
```

Comment: @dkar: What is the generated HTML source code that this produces? If the image doesn't load, that's an unrelated issue. Maybe `$last_file[0]` is wrong or doesn't actually point to an image. `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` seems totally wrong.

Comment: Because the $file_path[0] is wrong. The above outputs: src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/image_archive/filename" where filename is the value of $last_file[0]

Comment: The path is fine guys. This is what I get when I echo the $file_path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/image_archive/437460-1696-2012.png  As you can see is .PNG

Comment: The path does not work on a browser. Your script on the browser is not running from path root!!!

Comment: See if these help, you're missing a fundamental concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839522/php-relative-paths-and-directories http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130166/path-to-folder-from-localhost

Comment: browse to http://localhost/php_test/image_archive/437460-1696-2012.png and you should see your image. Browse to http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/image_archive/437460-1696-2012.png and you'll get a 404

Comment: Thanks. This last comment it was really helpful! It works fine now. Sorry I didn't get it earlier.